# Testing website content in different countries

Tags: localization

We have a website where different versions are served to readers based on the country they are from (using IP geo-location).

Is there a web app that would allow us to test how the website looks like to a user from a particular country? I have tried using proxies, but most proxies come with a limited set of countries and half of them don't work.

For example: A poll shown just to visitors from Brazil.

Answer (score 6):

Please forgive the self promotion, but I built a tool that does exactly this, which I hope you and others might find useful, called [GeoPeeker](http://www.geopeeker.com).

It remotely accesses a site from servers spread around the world, renders the page with webkit and sends back an image. It will also report the IP address of the site as it appears from that location.

It's free, it's easy to use, and feedback is welcome.

Comment: awesome! this is exactly what i needed to test my webapp

Answer (score 3):

There are some list of proxies available:

- http://www.proxy4free.com/list/webproxy_country1.html
- http://www.proxylist.net/sort/country
- http://www.samair.ru/proxy/type-01.htm

Except using proxies there is only the option to let the website overwrite the country by an URL parameter (for testing purposes). You can have the following url:

```
http://example.com/poll
```

Then you can add an parameter (which has to be of course being coded) to the url:

```
http://example.com/poll?country=brazil
```

Alternatively (to test the geolocation) you could also set the ip address (which of course needs also to be supported by the software):

```
http://example.com/poll?ip=1.2.3.4
```

Comment: This is in essence what we are doing right now. Was wondering if there was a web app that would take the URL and the list of countries to be tested against and produce screenshots (like browsershots).